# Android : Image qulity decreased using ImageLoader

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am using https://github.com/thest1/LazyList for image caching. I have to diaplay image in full screen. but there are big loss in quality of image.
which code i have to change for get original image.thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me why are you using LazyList when you have to display image on full screen.

Comment: @AB1209 Why not use LazyLoading for this case. The user might not want the UI thread to get hanged. That's really good to use..

Comment: @AB1209 I have many images to download from web and display them into gallery-View.

Comment: ok Andro Selva & Roshni.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for this method in the ImageLoader class,

```
  private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;

           while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

And remove the below lines from this method,

```
while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
```

This will make sure that your Image doesn't get scaled at all.

> But you have to keep in mind that, your app is vulnerable to OOM if you do this.

Comment: yes I agree with Andro Selva that In certain case you will get out of memory exception by removing this block of code

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageLoader.java` the function

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f)
```

is used to scale / resize ur image.

```
final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
```

increase this to increase the quality of the image. Make it 200 or something and try.